# What is the point of SSO with 2FA?

Tags: single-sign-on

I do not get the idea of using 2FA with SSO.

Is not the whole idea of SSO, that you do not have to log a second time for each application and with 2FA that is exactly the case.

Or is it like no SSO for the sake of security?

Answer (score 1):

Nope

- 2fa says 'when you have to authentication you have to have more than just a password'
- SSO means - once you have authenticated on to a central ID system, maybe using 2fa, maybe not , you do not have to authenticate to the individual apps

2 quite different things

---

It is possible for an SSO system to be configured to demand reauthentication or just the second factor in some circumstances. For example if the SSO system sees you are coming from an IP address its never seen before, of if you are trying to access a particularly sensitive app.

An SSO system is always a balance between end-user convenience and IT department paranoia